# How to Remove Duplicates Values after Merging Different Model Querysets in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

how to remove duplicates after merging two different models like this

```
import itertools

events_list = list(itertools.chain(events_list, speakers_list))
```

I am getting duplicate values in the Django REST serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union()`; here is [doc about union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)

```
qs1.union(qs2)
# no duplicates
```

By default, `union()`only gives you distinct values. If you want to allow duplicates, you use

```
qs1.union(qs2, all=True)
# allow duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

A `set` enforces uniqueness

```
events_list = set(itertools.chain(events_list, speakers_list))
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' error

Answer (score 0):

```
a = queryset1
b = queryset2
qs = a | b #removes duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct()` is doing this job :

```
queryset_final = queryset_with_duplicate.distinct()
```

Cf [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
> this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as
> Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result
> rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to
> get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d
> use distinct().